# login and register using Sqlite database in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, authentication

I want to register and login using Sqlite in my iOS app ? I have successfully registered and stored the data in a table. Now, I want to login by validating the username and password I registered. Please help me to successfully create login.

Comment: can you share some login code which is done from your end.

Comment: NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from peopleInfo where username=\"%@\" and password=\"%@\"",usernameTextField.text,passwordTextField.text];

Comment: peopleInfo is the table name where I have stored data from registration.Now, at the time of login, i need to validate if username n password exist in people info table., so for that what do i need to do ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do as follow might be work  for you.

```
  NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from peopleInfo where email=\"%@\" and password=\"%@\"",usernameTextField.text,passwordTextField.text];
  NSLog(@"%@",query);
  NSLog(@"%@",self.dbManager);
  NSArray* ary = [self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query];

  if (ary.count){
        //Login successfully
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"login successful" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }else{
        //Invalid username and password
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Unsuccessful" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Comment: This is the code i am using to execute query , where, @property (nonatomic, strong) DBManager *dbManager;        self.dbManager = [[DBManager alloc] initWithDatabaseFilename:@"sampledb.sql"]; but its not working

Comment: Do know about singleton class?

Comment: Please share content of DBManager class

Comment: NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from peopleInfo where email=\"%@\" and password=\"%@\"",usernameTextField.text,passwordTextField.text];
        NSLog(@"%@",query);
       [self.dbManager executeQuery:query];
        
        if (self.dbManager.affectedRows != 0){
            //Login successfully
            
        }else{
            //Invalid username and password
            
        }

Comment: Store this output in NSArray [self.dbManager executeQuery:query]

Comment: getting error while storing in array. Can you plz help and tell me how to store it ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. As you told, instead of executeQuery:query, I had to use loadDataFromDB:query. Thanks.